Linking visitMember_access and visitIfStatement methods of Antlr4
I am using ANTLR4 to read the C# files as I need to get all the conditional statements within the methods. For this purpose, I am overriding the visitIfStatement method, but the method does not have context of the current method. As I need to parse each method first and then go over its conditional statements sequentially. the below method gives me all the IF conditions of the input file. But I need the IF conditions method by method.
Question - Is there a way to set IfStatementContext within visitMethod_declaration so that I can get the conditions only within the methods. I need to do this because the object we are constructing has method body and then it has the if conditions within the methodBody
def visitIfStatement(self, ctx: CSharpParser.IfStatementContext):
    if_statement = self.getAllText(ctx.getPayload())
    for i in range(ctx.start.line, ctx.stop.line):
        if i not in self.codeLineNumbers:
            self.codeLineNumbers.append(i)
        else:
            self.presentFlag = True

    if not self.presentFlag:
        print("Before adding to dict" + if_statement)
        result = dict(conditional_stmt=if_statement,
                      start_line=ctx.start.line,
                      end_line=ctx.stop.line,
                      number_of_conditionals=self.ifcounter(if_statement)
                      )

        self.Program.DecisionNodeList.append(result)

    return self.visitChildren(ctx)


There are several ways to accomplish this. One way is to visit the if-statement and navigate up the parent chain to verify the if-statement is within a method. A second way is to first visit the method, ignoring if-statement visits. Create a second visitor that now handles if-statements, starting with all children of the method.

I did create second visitor using second approach, but I am unable to invoke the if statement method. Could you please share me a code example.

The grammar at https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/tree/ad46e0de8493dde768a7dd375c87703eee6433fd/csharp does not have a functioning Python3 target port. See the desc.xml target declaration. It only works for Java.

ok thanks. For now I am able to move forward by getting the child contexts of type IfStatementContext

Python reports an error "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'CSharpLexerBase'" with the generated CSharpLexer.py file. Are you using another grammar, or have you implemented the base class?

CSharpLexerBase is available in the git repo - https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/tree/master/csharp/CSharp

The existence of the port files in https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/tree/ad46e0de8493dde768a7dd375c87703eee6433fd/csharp/CSharp does not mean that the port works. You should always check the desc.xml for a grammar in grammars-v4 before using. When I set up the desc.xml's for grammars-v4, it didn't work at the time (likely because it has a preprocessor grammar). I generally don't remove the port code even though it goes untested. I guess the CSharp port of csharp/ now works, so I will update the grammar.
